# Smartphone cannot read NFC tag I use to enter my building

Tags: nfc

I have a tag that I use to enter my building.

[image]

And I see someone else in my building using his smartphone instead of the tag.

I have downloaded the NFC tools app and it doesn't read the tag. It doesn't even show any response, nothing. Note that the NFC on my phone works without problems.

What is the problem?

Comment: Are you sure it's an NFC tag? It's quite possible that those are RFID tags working on a different radio frequency and that the door lock just has a multi-frequency reader. Do you know the manufacturer of the reader at the door, or the type of the tag itself?

Comment: @u1686_grawity you maby right and this are RFID ? so how he did that with his phone ?

Comment: Well, again, it's possible that the door lock has a multi-frequency reader that recognizes both RFID tags _and_ NFC tags. (I don't know what's commercially available, as far as readers go, but I mean, that sounds plausible to me.)

Comment: @u1686_grawity  i think its RFID , i just saw the picture in google and its say its RFID , phone can read RFID  ?

Comment: @mikuzan - Most phones can’t as NFC is typically the only useful use case (I.e mobile payments)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tag in your photo is not an "NFC" type tag; it's an 125 kHz RFID tag. (You can tell from the number stamped on it... which, by the way, is the entire "tag data" that's stored inside. Knowing the number is enough to clone the RFID tag!)

NFC "Mifare" tags also exist in the exact same shape, which might be why your building has a reader that's capable of reading both types. However, they work in completely different frequencies, and I don't think any phones support 125 kHz tags. (I'm not really good at this whole RF thing, but I *suspect* that it would need a somewhat larger antenna than a smartphone can fit.)

Try asking the other person (or your building's security) about the app they use.